# Не могу изменить длину и ширину картинки в опере CSS HTML

Tags: css, html5

Возникла такая проблема, что не могу поменять длину и ширину картинки в Опере , в хроме все работает.

```css
.card {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button alt="" class="card" id="T-Shirt" )">
             <img class="card" src="img/card-img.png">
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно начать с того, что у Вас почему-то у кнопки и у картинки, находящейся внутри этой кнопки, задан один и тот же класс, что кажется не очень правильным.

Когда Вы задаёте параметры через этот класс, они применяются и к кнопке и к изображению внутри кнопки.

А если по делу - вот результат. В опере размер иконки меняется (установлен 100px).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можете просто изменять размер кнопки, размер картинки автоматически изменится

```html
 <style media="screen">
      .btn{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }
      .btn img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      <img src="https://s1.funon.cc/img/orig/201706/02/5930f9066a385.jpg" >
    </button>
```